# Trying to install Grails 2.2.1 always gives me Grails 2.1.1 through GVM

Tags: grails, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to get Grails 2.2.1 up and running.

I have GVM, so I tried `gvm install grails 2.2.1`, it seems to have succeeded.  I run the source command it tells me to and then `grails --version` and I see `Grails version: 2.1.1`.

Wat.

If I look in my user's `.gvm/grails` directory, and look at what the `current` symlink is pointing to, I see `/home/myuser/.gvm/grails/2.2.1`.  If I do a `which grails`, I get `/home/myuser/.gvm/grails/current/bin/grails`.

If I go to `/home/myuser/.gvm/grails/current/bin/grails` and run `./grails --version` I get `Grails version: 2.2.1`.

Does Grails 2.2.1 rely on Grails 2.1.1 in some way that would force GVM to also install it?

How do I correct my path so that when I run `grails`, it gives me the 2.2.1 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you manually install Grails 2.1.1 at some point?

The `~/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh` script is normally sourced in `.bashrc` and configures the environment.

Verify the GVM environment is sourced properly in bashrc:

```
$ echo $GVM_AVAILABLE
true
```

Verify the GRAILS_HOME environment variable:

```
$ echo $GRAILS_HOME
~/.gvm/grails/current
```

Make sure there is no alias defined for grails:

```
$ alias grails
-bash: alias: grails: not found
```

Check the path order:

```
$ echo $PATH | awk 'BEGIN { RS=":" } { print NR, $0 }'
```

Verify the grails link:

```
$ ls -l ~/.gvm/grails/current
lrwxlrwxlrwx 1 user user 35 Feb 19 11:01 ~/.gvm/grails/current -> ~/.gvm/grails/2.2.1
```

Comment: Echo'ing $GVM_AVAILABLE gives me nothing.  Just a blank line.  Everything else I think is as it should be.  I don't believe that grails was installed previously.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Can you include the redacted output of the above commands in your question?  Also you can set the environment manually with `source ~/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh` and give it a try.

Comment: So I think this is an instance of me not knowing what I was walking in to.  There are several version of Java already installed, as well as grails system wide.  My bad.